# Error in using Typed.js Typewriter effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

I am creating a Typing effect using HTML5 , CSS ,Javascript,Typed.js.
This is my code=

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 <p class ="TypeWirter_effect"></p>

  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js>"></script>     //This is downloaded from jquery's Website n pasted in same folder
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>         //This is downloaded from jquery's Website n pasted in same folder
 <script src="typed.min.js"></script>      //This is downloaded from Typed.js main Website n pasted in same folder


<script>
$(function() {
    $("#TypeWirter_effect").typed({
        strings: ["Want to learn Coding ?", "Want to learn C++","Java","Python"],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        loop: true,
        backSpeed: 30,
        showCursor: true,
        backDelay: 500,
        startDelay: 1000,
        contentType: 'text',
        backspace: function(curString, curStrPos) {


                    setTimeout(function () {

                                // check string array position
                                // on the first string, only delete one word
                                // the stopNum actually represents the amount of chars to
                                // keep in the current string. In my case it's 3.
                                if (curString.arrayPos == 20) {
                                    curString.stopNum = 14;
                                }
                                //every other time, delete the whole typed string
                                else {
                                    self.stopNum = 14;

                                }
                            }
                    )
                }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1)  When i run this the cursor always appear in the bottom [cursor problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe66bhw108bvfpt/1%20cursor%20prob.png?dl=0), i want the cursor right next to the ? mark at the end of this line but it always stays down.

2)  I want the second sentence "Want to learn C++" not to be erased completely and c++ 2 be erased and java to be appended to it .

I have read the documentation .But nothing seems to work Out .Help
Link of Documentation==(https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

`p` tag is a [paragraph](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp), change `p` tag to `span` tag and your problem will be resolved.

```
<span class="TypeWirter_effect"></span>
```

2)

Just add text before your typewritter effect text:

```
Want to learn <span class="TypeWirter_effect"></span>
```

And change strings to:

```
strings: ["Coding?", "C++?", "Java?", "Python?"]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Brownsugar/cncm5w0u/

---

I use a callback function to start language typewriter and let it loop.

First run the main sentence `.TypeWirter_effect`, and when it completed, run `.lang`.

HTML:

```
<span class="TypeWirter_effect"></span><span class="lang"></span>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $('.TypeWirter_effect').typed({
            strings: ['Want to learn Coding?', 'Want to learn '],
            typeSpeed: 50,
            backDelay: 3000,
            callback: function(){
                showLang(); // run another element
                $('.typed-cursor').first().hide(); // hide first cursor
            }
        });
});
function showLang() {
        $('.lang').typed({
            strings: ['C++', 'Java', 'Python'],
            typeSpeed: 50,
            backDelay: 2000,
            loop: true
        });
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Brownsugar/cncm5w0u/1/

Comment: i want 2 erase the 1st line completely "Want to learn Coding ?" nd i want 2 type this "Want to learn C++" then remove C++ n add Java in its place then remove Java add Python in its Place.If u tell me how this is done I will accept ur ans .+I have already voted up ur ans

Comment: V get stuck on this line "Want to learn C++/Java/Python". .I want a loop that as soon as u finish this line "Want to learn C++" then c++ erased then Java Erased then Python erased we come back to the 1st line "Want to Learn coding"". I want a loop from 1st sentence to second sentence then back

Comment: @GEEkSpoTTed I've tried my best, just made something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Brownsugar/cncm5w0u/2/